# Prove by induction $T(n) = T(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor)+n^2 \in \Theta (\log_2 n)$

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, induction

Text of the problem:

> Solve the following recurrence equation and prove it by applying the principle of
> induction:
> $T(n) = \begin{cases} 3, \ n \le 2 \\ T(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor)+n^2, \ n \ge 3 \end{cases}$

after doing the recursion tree, I find that the complexity (if I'm not wrong) is $ \Theta (\log_2 n) $

But I don't know how to do the induction step.

Comment: @PålGD $T(n) \in O(n^2) ? $

Comment: I thought so because when I went to each recursive call I work only on half of the previous one, so the height of the call tree should be $ \log_2 (n) $ and the complexity $ \sum_ {i = 1} ^ {\log_2 (n)} costwhile = \sum_ {i = 1} ^ {\log_2 (n)} \theta (1) = \theta (\log_2 (n)) $. do I have to think differently?

Comment: What do you mean with the notation $[ x ]$?

Comment: @Steven with $[x]$ I mean the floor, but I'm not able to write it in LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note that $T(n)$ is indeed **not in** $\Theta(\log n)$, which makes the proof difficult.

You need to understand that if $T(n) = T(n/2) + n^2$, then $T(n) = \Omega(n^2)$, since it uses $n^2$ time in the first "iteration" or "level".

You have made a mistake when drawing the call tree.  The call tree will look like this:

$$ n^2 + \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{n}{8}\right)^2 + \cdots + \left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)^2$$

You are right that the "tree" (or path) terminates after $\log_2(n)$ calls, so the summation should look like

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\log_2 n} \left( \frac{n}{2^i}\right)^2
=
\sum_{i=1}^{\log_2 n} \left( \frac{n^2}{2^{2i}}\right)
=
n^2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{\log_2 n} \left( \frac{1}{2^{2i}}\right)
=
n^2 \cdot c,
$$
for some constant $c$.

Now, since $T(1) = 3$, let's try to prove by induction that $T(n) \leq 3n^2$.

- Base case 1: $T(1) = 3 \leq 3\cdot 1^2 = 3$
- Base case 2: $T(2) = 3 \leq 3\cdot 2^2 = 12$
- Induction hypothesis: $T(n') \leq 3n^2$ for all $n' < n$.
- Induction step: $T(n) = T(n/2) + n^2 \leq 3 \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2 + n^2 = 3/4 n^2 + n^2 \leq 3n^2$.

Comment: Ps, if it weren't for the fact that $T(1) = 3$, you could show that $T(n) \leq 1.33333n^2$, where $c = 1.33333 \sim \sum_i^\infty 1/2^{2i}$.